# why $g_n(x)$ increase to $\chi_V(x)?$

Tags: measure-theory

From Rudin Book Page No : $49$

> **Theorem 2.18** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space in which every open set is $\sigma$-compact. Let $\lambda$ any positive Borel measure on $X$ such that $\lambda(K) < \infty$ for every compact set $K$. The $\lambda$ is regular.

Rudin say that let $V$ be open in $X$.Then $V= \bigcup K_i$, where $K_i$ is compact , $i=1,2,3,......$ By  Urysohn's lemma we can choose  $f_i$ so that $K_i \prec f_i \prec V$. let $g_n=\max(f_1,.....,f_n)$.Then $g_n \in C_c(X)$ and $g_n(x)$ increase to $\chi_V(x)$ at every point   $x \in X$

**My confusion** :why   $g_n(x)$ increase to $\chi_V(x)?$

**My thinking** : $K_i \prec f_i \prec V  \implies X= supp  f= \{x \in X : f_i(x) \neq 0\}$

so we have $f_i(x)=1$  for all  $ x \in K_i \implies  f_i(x)=1$ for all  $x\in V$

Therefore  $f_i(x)$ is  constant function for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$

I don’t understand why constant function increase to $\chi_V(x)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to think about this pointwise. Fix a point $x.$ Why must $g_n(x)$ tend to $\chi_V(x)$?

Well, if $\chi_V(x) = 0,$ then it's pretty clear that $g_n(x) = 0$ for each $x$ as well and so there's nothing to show. The tricky part is that if $\chi_V(x) = 1,$ then $g_n(x)$ goes to 1.

And for this, use that $K_i$ covers $V.$ So, if $\chi_V(x) = 1,$ then $x\in K_i$ for at least one value of $i.$ Then $f_i(x) = 1$, and so $g_i(x) = 1$ as well. It follows that $g_n(x) = 1$ for all $n \geq i,$ and you get the desired limit :)